# is it not possible to make first table row to have border only and separate the last rows of featured and normal?

Tags: css

```
    tr.featured:first-child{
      border-top: 5px solid red;
    }


<table>
    <tbody>
        {{#each i:idx}}

            <tr on-click="detail" class="{{featured ? 'featured' : ''}}">
                <td>
                  name JJ
                </td>
                <td>
                  address Texas
                </td>
                <td>
                  phone 4545-4555-455

                </td>
            </tr>

            {{#if active}}
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td colspan="3">
                       More more more information about us
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {{/if}}
       {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table row will be dynamically added if featured article for example. Attempted to have border top displayed on the first row, but instead all featured rows show border-top.

Headache trying to make the last featured row and last normal row separate by margin but it won't separate with margin. adding empty row is a cheat but it also means adding empty rows for all since it is dynamically printed.

Is it not possible to make first row to show only border and separate last rows: featured and normal? Please help

Comment: Please provide your table markup **in full**

Comment: `border-top` can be assigned to the whole table.. if there would be at least 1 featured row all the time :)

Comment: @Aprillion - I think same thing but there will be featured rows and standard rows without border top. I also have difficulties making last featured and last standard rows being separated by margin.

Comment: @George - ok i can only post the simple example not from view source which have full and long HTML code

Comment: You did ".list table" in your first block of CSS code when it should be just "table" or "table.list" because you applied .css to the table already. check this link http://jsfiddle.net/8h2v59ok/2/ to see it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understand what you want. See the example below

```
.featured:first-of-type {
 border-top: solid 1px #333;
}
```

**Or**

```
  .featured:nth-of-type(1) {
     border-top: solid 1px #333;
    }
```

The above applies border-top only to the first row

To select the last row, do this

```
.featured:last-of-type {
     /* do whatever you want for the last row here */
    }
```

**Note** margin property doesn't work with display:table-cell. Collapse the border and then use border spacing to achieve margin like spaces.

Comment: thanks so much. but first-of-type is not working either. it takes out background color and border top :(

Comment: You did ".list table" in your first block of CSS code when it should be just "table" or "table.list" because you applied .css to the table already. check this link http://jsfiddle.net/8h2v59ok/2/ to see it working. –  Sleek Geek 2

Comment: duh me and thanks very much -- you mention border spacing at the last row. i search on google but i am still not sure